# React router page redirect not correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've created a mini project and I am facing a problem like page is not redirecting and it's also print new content down the above content only. What I want to do is when user press link it should redirect completely to new page not with old content.

I'm sharing my git repo, please download it and help me to solve that error.

My git repo is: https://github.com/yashchks87/homepage.git

Comment: You have `'/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/homepage/src/Doctor.js'` in your react project. This will break the react app for other people since we do not have such a directory on our computers. Your paths should be starting from the root directory of the react app.

Comment: I tried to give absolute path as u suggested, but it's still creating problems. Can you write the path from git folders? So, I will update the repo...

Comment: I believe the correct path would be `'homepage/src/Doctor.js'`. Alternatively, you can use the `.` to say "start from current directory". EX: `'./Doctor.js'`.

Comment: I did that changes about path please check it... But still original problem persists.

Comment: I should mention that the comments I've posted so far only address the paths that will not exist on other computers. The "correct" path may be different depending on what React Router requires.

Comment: There are 3 paths :

first is importing using import statement,

while second is for Link component 

and third is for Route which are you suggesting and what should be that please mention that explicitly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the urls that you expect to receive.

Here is your `app.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Doctor from '/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/homepage/src/Doctor.js';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <Link to="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/homepage/src/Doctor.js">Sign Up</Link>
        </nav>
        <p>Hello this is homepage.</p>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/Users/yashchoksi/Documents/homepage/src/Doctor.js" component={Doctor}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Your `path` and `Link to` should point to the url path and not the file path.

I would suggest changing it to something like this:

```
render() {
    var homeMessage = () => {
        return (<p>Hello this is homepage.</p>);
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <Link to="/app/doctor/">Sign Up</Link>
            </nav>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/app/" component={homeMessage}/>
                <Route exact path="/app/doctor/" component={Doctor}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
     </Router>
   );
```

);

Comment: I made some changes as u suggested, but there's still original problem persists...

Comment: You need to be more specific about the errors you are receiving. Maybe show screenshots or logs. This way it will be easier to help you

Comment: Again, I see you are using `src/Doctors` as your path. THIS IS NOT THE DIRECTORY PATH. This should be the URL PATH. It should be something like `/app/doctors/` or something like that.

Comment: @morinx I cloned Yash Choksi's repo and then made the edits as shown in your answer. When I try to access the app page (`http://localhost:3000/app/`), I get an error: 

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of 'Route'.` I myself am not familiar with React Router, what is your take on this error?

Comment: So, anyone can suggest me final answer........ because I'm not getting the desired output..!

Comment: Ah, it seems to be because there was pure html inside of the component. `component={<p>Hello this is homepage.</p>}`. When I abstracted the html into it's own component (without exporting the component). It seems to work. I'm going to see if there is way to do this without creating a new component...

Comment: @Tyler yeah please check out other ways..... actually I want the way without creating component..