# React router component divison creates redundant printing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've also posted similar question and I got the answer, ***but as I divides component*** and merge them the routing creates some problem.

Please help me to find solution and for that i'm sharing my git repo:

https://github.com/yashchks87/homepage.git

Please download and see as I press sign up button I only want content of sign up page not home page....

Please check the src folder and check the homepage.js, NavBar.js these 2 files have the code insider Router tags please check it.

NavBar.js

```
export default class NavBar extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
              <Link to="/src/Doctor/">Sign Up</Link>
            </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/src/Doctor" component={Doctor}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Homepage.js

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  render(){
    var homeMessage = () => {
      return (<p>This is home page.</p>);
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
              <NavBar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={homeMessage}/>

              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the previous question in which I got the answer the link:

[React router page redirect not correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992825/react-router-page-redirect-not-correctly/48993056#48993056)

Comment: Do share the previous question as well. Also, please mention which file should we be concerned with in your git repo? If possible, include the code in the question as well

Comment: Please check my updated question. @KapilDevNeupane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a `Router at the top level` and not in each of the components, remove the `Router` from `Navbar` component and render `Navbar` as Default Route for it to get Route params.

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  render(){
    var homeMessage = () => {
      return (<p>This is home page.</p>);
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
              <Route component={NavBar} />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={homeMessage}/>

              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and NavBar

```
export default class NavBar extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
          <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
              <Link to="/src/Doctor/">Sign Up</Link>
            </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/src/Doctor" component={Doctor}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also as far as I understand you would not want to render Routes in Navbar, but in your Homepage. So you might consider configuring your Routes in HomePage and not in Navbar

```
<Router>
     <div>
          <Route component={NavBar} />
          <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={homeMessage}/>
             <Route path="/src/Doctor" component={Doctor}/>
          </Switch>
      </div>
</Router>
```

and in `Navbar` have just

```
 <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <Link to="/src/Doctor/">Sign Up</Link>
      </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: And what if I have footer component with similar links?? 

Can I write something like this??

              <Route component={NavBar} />
              <Route component={Footer} />
@Shubhum Khatri

Comment: I got the good documentation and help regarding reactjs but I don't find anything good about router. Can you share link if you know anything about router? @Shubhum Khatri

Comment: ReactTraining docs are really good,plus they provide demo examples, from which you can learn https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy